# how to fix ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECRM]? [Debian]

Tags: debian, acpi

what does this means and how do I correct it?

```
# journalctl | grep -a "ACPI Error"
Mar 22 18:16:58 debian kernel: ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECRM] ((____ptrval____)) [EmbeddedControl] (20180810/evregion-132)
Mar 22 18:16:58 debian kernel: ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20180810/exfldio-265)
Mar 22 18:16:58 debian kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.RDEC, AE_NOT_EXIST (20180810/psparse-516)
Mar 22 18:16:58 debian kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.TZS0._TMP, AE_NOT_EXIST (20180810/psparse-516)
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you have Debian, this is also on my Ubuntu 18.04/Mint 19.3.

This is just error reporting and not a bug, according to Uncle Archie:

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/52777

Funnily(not) I also run an aging European(ECRM?), Lenovo B590 with the same error also seen on other Lenovos', given the age of the BIOS(circa 2013/5), the timing (just after keyboard definitions are loaded)
[More info is found here, OUCH!](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_5_1release.pdf#page%3D239).

My auth.log shows **(Take note of the last 2 entries)**:

```
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd-logind[788]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Power Button)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd-logind[788]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd-logind[788]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd-logind[788]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd-logind[788]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event6 (ThinkPad Extra Buttons)
```

**And syslog fails before they are all complete**:

```
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.661872] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (on-line)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.661949] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.661964] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662001] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxxx kernel: [    1.662009] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662048] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662057] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662725] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECRM] ((____ptrval____)) [EmbeddedControl] (20190703/evregion-132)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662731] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20190703/exfldio-265)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662739] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [MDEC]
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662740] Initialized Arguments for Method [MDEC]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662741]   Arg0:   (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000090
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662745]   Arg1:   (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Integer 00000000000000FE
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662747]   Arg2:   (____ptrval____) <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662751] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.MDEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20190703/psparse-531)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662759] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZS0._SCP due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20190703/psparse-531)
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662912] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
Jun 17 10:26:38 xxxx kernel: [    1.662913] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZS0] (39 C)
```

**EDIT**

<del>Could you post the previous 6 lines of auth.log and sys.log *(use date/timestamp)* to see if there are any similarities, or any other thoughts on this?</del>

<del>Much appreciated.</del>

**Hey I found the culprit, ***well it worked for me!***:** Add '**acpi=off**`.

After testing on my ancient Lenovo B590, several times, by editing ***using 'e' on my grub menu*** to:

```
 BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-lowlatency root=UUID=51e6fcad-3f35-d601-5040-fcad3f35d601 ro acpi=off quiet splash
```

Got lucky , only 3 boots to find it , running 3 days no problems so far, enjoy!

Hopefully doesn't damage anything else, [the spec is a few pages down here.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=acpi%20off)

Comment: thank for the tipps and links! that PDF fills a knowledge-gap I had! I'll post the data in a couple of days. I am slowly moving away from that system...

Comment: Knowledge  [___GAPE!____](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?). Will try the acpi  params later in the week, specifically debugging with region specific states off. currently running Ubuntu 18.04/Mint 19.3 'lowlatency' kernel + brcm-source-kernel, otherwise straight out of someone's box..